# How to stop scrollIntoView?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I am using this jQuery plugin [`jQuery.scrollIntoView`](https://github.com/Arwid/jQuery.scrollIntoView).

When I click the ID(`#back` and `#forward`), this plug-in works properly.

But, if I click the same id, I want to stop the scroll event.

What should I use? `.stop()`? `.stopPropgation()`?

I tried this but it did not work...

```
var _doc = document;
var notify = function() {
// ...
}; 
$(function() {
  $(_doc.getElementById('back')).click(function(){
    $(_doc.getElementById('top')).scrollintoview({ duration: 3000, easing: 'easeOutQuint', complete: notify });
  });
  $(_doc.getElementById('forward')).click(function(){
    $('p:last').scrollintoview({ duration: 3000, easing: 'easeOutQuint', complete: notify });
  });
});
```

What should I do?